# Unmet dependencies - problem installing packages (linux-headers)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

When installing any package with apt-get, I run into this problem:

```
# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-headers-3.2.0-23-virtual : Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-23 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So after attempting apt-get -f install I get this:

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-23
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-23
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 192 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 56.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 37808 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-headers-3.2.0-23 (from .../linux-headers-3.2.0-23_3.2.0-23.36_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-23_3.2.0-23.36_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/arch/openrisc/include/asm/bitops/__ffs.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23/arch/openrisc/include/asm/bitops/__ffs.h'): No such file or directory
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-23_3.2.0-23.36_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Attempting to install the package fails using dpkg aswell. Hoping a solution to this can help others out in the future.